# Passing paramaters to flask __init__.py

Tags: python-2.7, configuration, flask

I have a flask application that I would like to operate different when in production, unit testing, functional testing, and performance testing. Flasks one debug operation doesn't cover what I want to do, I was wondering if there is any way to pass parameters to flasks `__init__.py.`

I have several different scripts which build my app and create my data structures.

I know I can do this using environment variables but I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Have you seen http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: No, I haven't seen this extension. I'll have to give this a shot monday and see if it works with my project.

Comment: @SeanVieira So I tried using flask-script and I found it more cumbersome then just having multiple config files and having each file that creates a flask app also set the config files location and a environment variable. I may also need to eventually refactor and use flask-script. 

This might have been the right solution had I started with flask-script and only had a single file that runs commands (similar to django's manage.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution hybrid solution between my inital plan and Seans suggestion. I use multiple config files and set a environment variable before each kind of app instance. This means that you need to use
 `from os import environ`

`environ["APP_SETTINGS"] = "config.py"`

before every `import app` call. The best approach to this problem is to use flask-script as Sean suggests and to have a `python manage.py request` where request could range from

`run_unit_tests` to `run_server`

and that manage script sets the environment variable (as well as builds the database, sets up a profiler, or anything else you need).